# DatagridView boolean values update to database

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, boolean

I'm having an issue when I update values from a datagridview row to the database. The issue is that I have designed the table in the DB with certain fields as "bit" data type to store boolean value flags.

When i assign the datatable to the datagridview the system aytomatically displays these certain fields as checkboxes, which suits me just fine.

But when I try to update these values back to the database the boolean values go bananas.....Here is my code...

```
int fragileChk = (Convert.ToBoolean(aRow.Cells[12].Value) ? 1 : 0);
int inflamChk = (Convert.ToBoolean(aRow.Cells[13].Value) ? 1 : 0);
int biologicalChk = (Convert.ToBoolean(aRow.Cells[15].Value) ? 1 : 0);
int emergencyChk = (Convert.ToBoolean(aRow.Cells[16].Value) ? 1 : 0);
int usedChk = (Convert.ToBoolean(aRow.Cells[25].Value) ? 1 : 0);
int offerChk = (Convert.ToBoolean(aRow.Cells[27].Value) ? 1 : 0);

string err;
string sqlComm = "UPDATE [70_warehouse_lines] SET " +
                 "ProductDescr = '" + aRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "', " +
                 "PartNumber = '" + aRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "', " +
                 "SerialNumber = '" + aRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString() + "', " +
                 "Quanitity = " + aRow.Cells[8].Value + ", " +
                 "Weight = " + aRow.Cells[10].Value + ", " +
                 "FragileFlag = " + fragileChk + ", " +
                 "InflammableFlag =" + inflamChk + ", " +
                 "BiologicalFlag = " + biologicalChk + ", " +
                 "EmergencyFlag = " + emergencyChk + ", " +
                 "SpecialInstructions = '" + aRow.Cells[17].Value.ToString() + "', " +
                 "ShopCostPrice = " + aRow.Cells[19].Value + ", " +
                 "RetailPrice1  = " + aRow.Cells[20].Value + ", " +
                 "RetailPrice2 = " + aRow.Cells[21].Value + ", " +
                 "WholePrice1 = " + aRow.Cells[22].Value + ", " +
                 "WholePrice2 = " + aRow.Cells[23].Value + ", " +
                 "CalculatedPrice = " + aRow.Cells[24].Value + ", " +
                 "UsedParts = " + usedChk + ", " +
                 "TimesProcessed = " + aRow.Cells[26].Value + ", " +
                 "OnOffer = " + offerChk + ", " +
                 "NotesPerPart = '" + aRow.Cells[28].Value.ToString() + "' " +
                 "WHERE WarehouseLineID = '" + aRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";

myConn.ExecSqlCmd(sqlComm, out err);
```

any ideas ? (I have declared int values just for diagnostic purposes. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please describe more accurately your error.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your error? I.e. what do you mean by "boolean values go bananas"? I recommend adding your stack trace and/or output to the question.

Comment: The values on screen (e.g. a checked checkbox) are not updated in the database.

Comment: Meaning that if I have checked a checkbox, I expect the value to be updated in the DB and after the data table reload, I expect to see the changes on the datagrid. Unfortunately it does not happen. That's what I'm trying to find out. Why specifically the boolean values are not updated.

Comment: Thats not the way to build SQL - use parameters; if it is one table, use a datasource and update using a DataAdapter.

Comment: These are symptoms of a different database at play. What is your connection string? And can you add the code of ExecSqlCmd?

Answer (score 0):

Always use parameterised query, Using parameters helps prevent SQL Injection attacks when the database is used in conjunction with a program interface.
also you can specify datatype in parameterised query that will helpfull in your case.

```
string sqlComm = "UPDATE [70_warehouse_lines] SET " +
                             "ProductDescr = @ProductDescr " +
                             "PartNumber = @PartNumber " +
                             "SerialNumber = @SerialNumber  " +
                             "Quanitity = @Quanitity" +
                             "Weight = @Weight" +
                             "FragileFlag = @FragileFlag" +
                             "InflammableFlag = @InflammableFlag" +
                             "BiologicalFlag = @BiologicalFlag" +
                             "EmergencyFlag = @EmergencyFlag" +
                             "SpecialInstructions = @SpecialInstructions " +
                             "ShopCostPrice = @ShopCostPrice" +
                             "RetailPrice1  = @RetailPrice1" +
                             "RetailPrice2 = @RetailPrice2 " +
                             "WholePrice1 = @WholePrice1 " +
                             "WholePrice2 = @WholePrice2 " +
                             "CalculatedPrice = @CalculatedPrice " +
                             "UsedParts = @UsedParts  " +
                             "TimesProcessed = @TimesProcessed " +
                             "OnOffer = @OnOffer  " +
                             "NotesPerPart = @NotesPerPart" +
                             "WHERE WarehouseLineID = @WarehouseLineID ";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlComm);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FragileFlag", MySqlDbType.Bit).Value = (Convert.ToBoolean(aRow.Cells[12].Value) ? 1 : 0);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@InflammableFlag", MySqlDbType.Bit).Value=(Convert.ToBoolean(aRow.Cells[13].Value) ? 1 : 0);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BiologicalFlag", MySqlDbType.Bit).Value=(Convert.ToBoolean(aRow.Cells[15].Value) ? 1 : 0);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmergencyFlag", MySqlDbType.Bit).Value = (Convert.ToBoolean(aRow.Cells[16].Value) ? 1 : 0);
....................................
....................................
....................................
    and so on

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I most usually use parameterized queries in my code. For this I wanted to execute a plain SQL Command. I'm aware of SQL injection attacks since they appeared years back :) ...I'll try your solution and let you know.

Comment: Dexter, unfortunately it did not work, even with parameters....Plutonix, how would you use the data adapter to update the values ? the problem, now that I have looked it up a bit more, is that the values are not reflected on the variables passed for updating. as if the click event on the cell did not work !...any ideas ?

Comment: can you please share your complete code so we can understand what you want to do and what problems you are facing with code

Comment: There is no issue with my code in specific. The issue I'm facing and I'm trying to solve is, why when I click on the checkbox column of the datagridview, the value does not change. I'll try something and if it works i'll post it here. Thank you in advance